# C++ Output being printed twice

Tags: c++, c++11

When i was working on a program i printed a string "IN MAIN" once but it printed twice. Can someone explain this behavior to me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>


std::string checkWin(std::vector<std::vector<int>> board){
    bool win = false;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < board.size(); i++){
        int count = 0;
        for(int j = 1 ; j < board[0].size(); j++){
            if(board[i][j-1] == board[i][j]) count++;
        }
        if(count == board[0].size()-2) return "R"+i;
    }
    return "null";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> board=
    {
        {'x','o','x'},
        {'o','o','o'},
        {'x','x','o'}
    };
    std::cout<<"IN MAIN";
    std::cout<<checkWin(board);
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/VbgZ1y

Comment: Clue: what do you think `"R"+i` does? It does not append a number to a string.

Comment: Please read [ask]. If nothing else, your title gives a very poor description of what this question is about. It could also do with a more detailed explanation of what exactly you do not understand about this code.

Comment: Funny that your ideone sample does not do what you claim it does. That could be due to *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: "Any sufficiently advanced undefined behavior is indistinguishable from magic"

Comment: When I am compiling it and execute it, I get `IN MAINnull` as output...

Comment: @Encryptor: due to the `"R"+i` you have **Undefined Behavior**, and just about anything, including nothing, can happen. In particular, readers may find it difficult to reproduce your results exactly.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"R"+i` does not append a number to a string. `"R"` is an array of `char`, containing the values `{'R', '\0'}`. This array decays to a pointer to the first `char` when you add a number to it, doing pointer arithmetic. You end up with a pointer to who-knows-what, which then gets turned into a `std::string`, giving you garbage. This is called [*Undefined Behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Your program could do absolutely anything at all, including appearing to work normally. It is very dangerous.

String literals are all stored in the same area of memory when the program runs, so `"R"` is stored somewhere close to `"IN MAIN"` and `"null"`. I guess what is happening is that the bad pointer arithmetic moves you from the start of `"R"` to the start of `"IN MAIN"`, which is why that is printed. But this is definitely not guaranteed.

There are various ways to build up a string correctly, the best probably being [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) mentioned by Joachim Pileborg above. Then you *can* use `+` to concatenate `std::string` objects. Another option is using an [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).